# DASH mpd restream and Convert to m3u8 HLS

Tags: python, php, http-live-streaming, m3u8, mpd

Can i have some chance taking stream source in the DASH mpd format VIDEO and then convert it to m3u8 HLS format to stream agane.
I will take video stream web link with mpd format, from other web server. https://xxxxx/xxxxx.mpd 
I have DASH mpd License.
And i want convert the mpd to m3u8 HLS format.

Can i have some chanse to doo that ?
Someone have some expiriance with that. I cant Find any solution about that.

Kind Regards